# MySQL Check Constraints

Tags: mysql, constraints, create-table

I have a database table like so:

```
-- Table KNOWN_AS
create table `known_as`(
id int not null auto_increment,
person_id int not null,
default_name boolean not null,
first_name varchar(100) not null,
middle_name_1 varchar(100),
middle_name_2 varchar(100),
middle_name_3 varchar(100),
last_name varchar(100),
primary key(id),
foreign key(person_id) references `person`(id)
) engine=innodb;
```

When inserting values, I want to check that each unique "person_id" has exactly one true "default_name".

All googling etc I've done so far has resulted in pages explaining how to keep a value non-negative, or how to make sure a value is unique - not how to check one value is unique amongst multiple entries (but not *ALL*).

Any help / pointers much appreciated!!

Comment: Your question refers to two completely different things: 1. *I want to check that each unique "person_id" has exactly one true "default_name"* and 2. *how to check one value is unique amongst multiple entries (but not ALL).*   Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > I want to check that each unique "person_id" has exactly one true "default_name"

   Why not store `default_name` as a `NOT NULL` column in the `person` table?
2. > how to check one value is unique amongst multiple entries (but not ALL)

   Define a `UNIQUE` index over the composite `(person_id, default_name)`:

   ```
    ALTER TABLE known_as ADD UNIQUE INDEX (person_id, default_name);
   ```

Comment: Thanks - I was clearly going in the wrong direction with constraints :)